# Suitable icon for downloads count & file size, suggestion please - flutter

Tags: flutter, icons, material-icons

I need suggestion about what I icon to use to denote the number of downloads of a file and it's file size.

**Little background:**
In one of my flutter apps, user can download a specific document and I would like to give some context to user by showing the number of downloads for that file and that file's size but I'm not sure on what'd be the suitable icon to use.

As of now I'm just putting text.

Ex: *`thumbs_up_alt(_outlined)` 234 Likes* | *21 MB* | *345 downloads*.

But, icons would make more sense and are better right! Also, as these 2 are being adjacent to eachother these icons should be distinctive to understand. please give your suggestions.

*Note:* I prefer to use default material icons those come in flutter. I can use something from pub.dev too, if need be. But, again, not sure which icon to use.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

These are few good ones, [image]

check all of them [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html)

If it were me, I'd have used one of these [image]

in a row, followed by no. of downloads.

Comment: Provided that these details are being put just below the document title, which already has a download button beside the title, these icons might be little confusing. but, I could go with one of these if found nothing else. I'm still not sure on what icon to choose for number of downloads!

Comment: Else you can have a favorite icon followed by number

Comment: Favorite icon may not be a suitable one for denoting downloads count right! Moreover, I'm having one such thing for each document already. Ex: `234 Likes` preceding it with `thumbs_up_alt_outlined` icon denoting how many others liked it. Once user likes a specific document I'm changing icon to `thumbs_up_alt`.   So, favorites isn't suitable one here, in my case. I editing my question with that info too now.